# % height if applied to tbody - doesn't work in FireFox & Microsoft Edge / IE but works in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have following code - 
Intention is to get fixed headers of table with scrollable tobody.

If I use height of tbody in pixels or in vh it works in chrome, firefox, or in microsoft browsers.

but if I use % height for tbody - it works only in chrome.

Anyone has any idea how to get it working in Firefox or Edge ?

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title></title>
     <style type="text/css">
        
    
        .tableWrapper{
      width:80%;
      height:80vh;
      border:1px solid red;
     }
    
     table{
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border:1px solid blue;
      height:100%;
      position:relative;
      table-layout: fixed;
     }
     thead,tbody{
      display:block;
      
     }
     
     td,th{
      border:1px solid blue;
      width:70px;
      height:20px;
     }
     tbody{
      height:30vh;
      border:2px solid yellow;
      overflow-y: auto;
     }
    
    
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
     <h1>Table</h1>
     <div class="tableWrapper">
      
      <table>
       <thead>
        <tr>
         <th><br>sr no</th>
         <th>First Name</th>
         <th>Middle Name</th>
         <th>last Name</th>
         <th>Address</th>
         <th>Age</th>
         <th><br>Sex<br></th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
    
       <tfoot>
        
       </tfoot>
      </table>
    
     </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: what version of IE do you use?

Comment: add this to css `html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%;}`

Comment: IE 11.665 on windows 10.

the code you suggested is not helping.

Comment: do you mean that `height:30vh;` does not work?

Comment: If is works in Chrome, that should be considered a bug. Percentage heights should only work where the containing block has an explicitly specified height. The containing block of the tbody set to `display:block` is the anonymous table cell object generated between it and the table element. Since that has no explicit height, the percentage should be ignored and treated as "auto", which is what the other browsers do.

Comment: FWIW `tbody {display:block;}` also causes differences between the browsers. Can you explain why you think you need that?

Comment: @MrLister - I need it because I want fixed table header & scroll able table body that is fixed headers & scroll able table data

Comment: @Alohci - for the reasons you have mentioned I have used tableWrapper div. There I have given width=80% & height = 80vh. 
Below that comes table which also has explicit height - width in this case is getting calculated as sum of column's width as the table-layout is set to fixed.
And as you rightly mentioned tbody is set to display:block -which has it's parent table - which has explicit height & it's width get's calculated. Then why the % height on tbody is not working, because in this case from tbody upwards - everyone (table, & it's wrapper) has explicit width & height. 
Please clarify

Comment: We need to distinguish between "parent element" and "containing block". It is the "containing block" that must have a specified height. The "parent element" of the tbody is the table element, but the "containing block" of the tbody element is a generated table-cell box. This generated box does not have a specified height. Read [CSS 2.2 17.2.1 Anonymous table objects](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/tables.html#anonymous-boxes) for more information on the generated boxes.

Comment: .. and it is not possible to specify a height on those anonymous table objects.

Comment: @Alohci - Yes your references are correct & whatever you say is correct too.. But I am not convinced as - containing block - I refer to it as closest positioned ancestor - which has explicit dimensions & position too (relative in this case). According to which the descendant should calculate it's dimensions - if given in %. And when I say tbody{display:block;} it's containing block - which is table has both position(relative) & dimensions - so tbody should calculate the height according to it's containing block.Can I mail you separately- so that we can discuss there.

Comment: @NITINTAKALE - A better approach would be to ask a new question about your understanding of containing blocks. That way you're more likely to get inputs from several sources, rather than just me, and the answers are visible for future visitors to the site. But "closest positioned ancestor" only applies to absolute positioned elements, and your tbody is not one of those.

Comment: @Alohci - No Closest positioned ancestors applies to relatively positioned, absolutely positioned & fixed positioned elements.
As you suggested I will raise another question.

Comment: @Alohci - Please check my new question - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52643595/closest-positioned-ancestor-width-height-doesnt-work-on-html-tbody